# Fréchet inception distance (FID) Score for same vectors is not zero

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, computer-vision, generative-adversarial-network

I was trying to use the implementation of FID score from this resource: https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-implement-the-frechet-inception-distance-fid-from-scratch/ but when I run the FID score for the same vectors (`act1`) I expected the FID score to be 0, instead I am getting a large number. Where am I  going wrong?

```
# example of calculating the frechet inception distance
import numpy
from numpy import cov
from numpy import trace
from numpy import iscomplexobj
from numpy.random import random
from scipy.linalg import sqrtm

# calculate frechet inception distance
def calculate_fid(act1, act2):
    # calculate mean and covariance statistics
    mu1, sigma1 = act1.mean(axis=0), cov(act1, rowvar=False)
    mu2, sigma2 = act2.mean(axis=0), cov(act2, rowvar=False)
    # calculate sum squared difference between means
    ssdiff = numpy.sum((mu1 - mu2)**2.0)
    # calculate sqrt of product between cov
    covmean = sqrtm(sigma1.dot(sigma2))
    # check and correct imaginary numbers from sqrt
    if iscomplexobj(covmean):
        covmean = covmean.real
    # calculate score
    fid = ssdiff + trace(sigma1 + sigma2 - 2.0 * covmean)
    return fid

# define two collections of activations
act1 = random(10*2048)
act1 = act1.reshape((10,2048))
act2 = random(10*2048)
act2 = act2.reshape((10,2048))
# fid between act1 and act1
fid = calculate_fid(act1, act1)
print('FID (same): %.3f' % fid)
# fid between act1 and act2
fid = calculate_fid(act1, act2)
print('FID (different): %.3f' % fid)
```

Results:

```
FID (same): -66113130760175032991744.000
FID (different): -55213970774324510299478046898216203619608871777363092441300193790394368.000
```

I was expecting the fid score for the same vectors to be zero but it is coming up as large number which was contrary to what I understood of FID scores and what is demonstrated in the source linked above.

Comment: do you think those huge numbers are correct? did you step through the calculations and inspect intermediate results?

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz I ran the code for the below dimensions of the random vector act1 - (10*32, 10*64, ....... , 10*4096). The other values looked alright but I found a rapid increase in the square root of product in covariance(covmean) and error started coming up from the Dimension - 10*512

Results:
Dimensions: 10*256
FID_Score: -3.410156860367275e-06 (Rounded to 0), Square Root Mean: 0.07221308759922525

Dimensions: 10*512
FID Score: -544.0, Square Root Mean: 780409269897557.8

Dimensions: 10*1024
FID Score: 4.1320706725109396e+21, Square Root Mean: -6.988481070030121e+32

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend talking to the author of that blog post. if they can't explain this, ditch the article and look for real scientific publications or textbooks.

Comment: It is quite logical that it should return 0, indeed. And it does on a few (smaller — sqrtm is long) examples I ran. But  `sqrtm` is a very complex process, that accumulates lot of error. You can easily see, with some `sqrtm((A:=random((10,20))).T@A@A.T@A)-A.T@A` that when that 20 rises, error so does, and, at some point, explodes.

Comment: Side note 1: `random` can accept a shape parameter. No need to `random(H*W).reshape((H,W))`. You can directly `random((10,2048))`

Comment: Side note 2 : are you sure of those shapes? Because, basically, that means that you have 2048×2048 covariance matrices. Your life would be easier if it were 10x10 matrices. In other words, if you were computing from `random((2048,10))` data. Or the fid distance of the transposed matrices. I know nothing of your problem, so can't tell which is the good one. But it seems unrealistic that a paper suggest to compute the `sqrtm` of a 2048,2048 full matrix as an actual solution. On the contrary, usually, the whole point of working on covariance, is that the size of the data doesn't matter any more

Comment: So, again, I know nothing of what you are doing. But I would double check that it is not the fid distance of 2048×10 arrays that you want to compute (2048 values of 10 variables), and not the one of 10×2048 arrays.

Comment: Thanks @ChristophRackwitz I will check with the author and will update here what is the result of the same